# how to use 'react-native-google-mobile-ads' in my expo managed app?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm developing this app specially for iOS and I want to know whether to use 'react-native-google-mobile-ads' do I need to eject the app? If so how to do it as I'm developing the app using a windows pc?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [expo prebuild](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/), this will allow you to add native code without ejecting the expo.

Comment: Thanks. I think the app can be publish after adding native code in the normal way by using eas build. To test it during development I think expo development builds can be used but the only problem is to run ios development build I need to have a mac? is there a way to run an ios stimulator on windows?

Comment: AFAIK to run a build you can use https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/